# Google search "go to results" keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome if I make a Google search and have a list of results, is there a keyboard shortcut to go to the links quickly and switch between the list of results? E.g. in Opera one can achieve it by pressing Tab and using the Up/Down arrows.

Comment: See answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1237754/407543

Answer (score 2):

Google have removed this feature, so you can't just turn it out like you used to be able to. The way you *used* to be able to do this was through:

Google Search > Settings > Search Settings > Google Instant Prediction > On

I was so sad to see this feature go that I wrote a hack to re-engineer it last night. So far it only works with Google Chrome, but can be adapted to work with all the others:

1. Install Chrome extension [ShortKeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck).
2. Click on the ShortKeys menu and select "Options"
   [image]
3. Click on "Add" and fill in the following fields:

**Keyboard Shortcut:** tab

**Behavior:** Run JavaScript

**Label as:** Result Picker

4. Paste the following JavaScript into the **JavaScript code to run:**

   ```
   document.selectedResultId=0
   function selectResult(newId){
       els = document.querySelectorAll("div.r h3")
       if(newId < 0 || newId >= els.length)
           return  //Could modify for page nav...?
       rp = document.getElementById("result-pointer")
       if(rp != null){
           rp.remove()
       }
       document.selectedResultId=newId
       el = els[newId]
       lnk = el.firstElementChild
       el.innerHTML = "<div id=\"result-pointer\" style=\"position:absolute;left:-15px;\">&gt;</div>" + el.innerHTML
       lnk.focus()
   }
   document.onkeyup=function(event){
       if(event.keyCode==38)
           selectResult(document.selectedResultId-1)
       if(event.keyCode==40)
           selectResult(document.selectedResultId+1)
       if(event.keyCode==13){
         var el = document.querySelectorAll("div.r h3")[document.selectedResultId]
         var lnk = el.parentElement
         var url = lnk.href
         if(event.ctrlKey){
           var win = window.open(url,"_blank")
           win.blur()
           window.open().close()
         }
         else{
           document.location = url
         }
       }
   }
   selectResult(0)
   ```
5. Configure the **Activation Settings**:

**Active while in form fields** (Checked)

**Websites** (Only specific sites)

**URLS (one per line)**: `*.google.*`

This is what the Options page should look like

[image: ShortKeys Options Page]

6. Click Save and then close your browser.

***Instructions:***

- When you restart you should see a little blue ">" appear by search
  results when you hit tab.
- The up/down arrow keys make it cycle through the results.
- Hitting "Enter" will navigate to the highlighted result.
- Hitting "Ctrl+Enter" to open the result in a new tab. (note: on a Mac this is the actual `control` key, not `command`)

Happy Searching!

Comment: +100 Thank you so much for implementing this! Now that Google Instant is gone (as of July 2017) we had no keyboard shortcuts, but you restored them!!

Comment: @BradCupit did you get it to work?

Comment: your steps above? yes, they definitely work! Thank you so much!!

Comment: On a Mac I was able to get Cmd+Enter to open tabs in the background. Change `document.onkeyup` to `document.onkeydown`, then change `if(event.ctrlKey){` to `if(event.metaKey){` and remove the calls to `win.blur()` and `window.open().close()`

Comment: I have a mac at home and will play around with it. I agree we need "Apple+enter" for new window.

Comment: @BradCupit - updated to match new Google HTML.

Comment: I had to change the query selector today to `.rc > div.yuRUbf`. We should probably have a github repo where we can share changes. Since you're the original author you could create the repo and give it a permissive license like Apache or MIT, then I'd be happy to contribute.

Comment: @BradCupit - here you (I mean, we) go... https://github.com/RobinH-J/SearchingShortcuts

Comment: excellent! I'll get you a pull request!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you press `TAB` button once to get to the first result. And then you can select with the down/up buttons.

Comment: It does not work for me. Is it a glitch?

Comment: That's strange, because it definitely works for me. I'm in ubuntu, maybe there ar differences between OSes

Comment: The answer below also works for me

Comment: This only works in Chrome if you have [Google Instant](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186645?hl=en) enabled in your browser settings. I don't know why.

Comment: unfortunately Google has disabled Google Instant as of July 2017

Answer (score 0):

Just use your arrow keys <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↕</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you are at the desired result.