# How to use keyboard to navigate google search results (now that instant search is dead)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, search, google-search

As of today, Google Instant Search [is dead](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674).
This is what it used to look like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANVT56wlmTo

I never cared much for the instant display of results while I typed. However, I did use, hundreds of times a day, the keyboard shortcuts it allowed.

For those that never used it - with instant search turned on, you could:

- Press enter after a search, and use the up/down keys to move a 'pointer' 
  down through the results
- Then press 'enter' to open a search result being pointed at
- At any point in time, typing letters/numbers on the keyboard would refocus on the search bar
- Pressing enter with a result highlighted could be combined with the ctrl modifier to open a result in a new tab.

I find the mouse quite difficult to use and try to avoid it when possible. Is there a tool or script I could use to replicate the keyboard behaviour that instant search used to give me?

Previous questions have asked (and been answered) in the era of instant search (e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1234483/how-to-enable-keyboard-navigation-in-google-search-results), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1103550/google-search-go-to-results-keyboard-shortcut) and my previous question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/509192/tab-enter-no-longer-taking-me-to-first-google-search-result-in-chrome?rq=1)), while I'm looking for a non-google replacement with the same functionality.

I am using Chrome on Ubuntu 15.01.

Comment: You remember correctly, it used to work fine. It seems it has gone away along with the _instant search_. http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674 . 
But are you sure the instant search is still working for you, though? For me, it doesn't do a search before I press enter any more. (I like that behaviour, but I want the little blue arrow back, like you do.)

Comment: this is extremely disappointing .... it seems the hotkey to use '/' to return to the search bar has also gone away with instant search

Comment: In the same position as you. It's bizarre the most popular web page on the planet has messed up this simple UX design. I'm sure a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script could work but not the most desired solution.

Comment: You can still navigate the search results using the Tab key.

Comment: @Seth - I don't think I'm able to do that. What sequence of keystrokes do you use to make this work? If I type into the search box on google.com, then press enter then tab, the focus shifts to a button to the right but it doesn't allow me to open a search result unless I press tab 17 times. Is that the use of tab you mean?

Comment: Yes, it's not attractive but one of the options to navigate the site using a keyboard.

Comment: Oh dear - so it is official! +1 to Bill for sourcing this article. I was hoping this was a bug that might go away... :-(

Comment: Actually, Bill. I think you should close this question because it's too similar to this one: https://superuser.com/questions/509192/tab-enter-no-longer-taking-me-to-first-google-search-result-in-chrome

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-for-go/naaaebidllcopodoaeeedjnbibinnpid/related?hl=en&gl=US This one works perfectly out of the box for me! Chrome only obvi.

Comment: On that same topic, is there any option available for Firefox?

Comment: @hazerd You may try [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/). The equivalent for Chrome would be [cVim](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cvim/ihlenndgcmojhcghmfjfneahoeklbjjh?hl=en)

Comment: [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) has this by default and (!) respects your privacy.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me: https://superuser.com/a/1235114/99219

Answer (score 27):

Google have removed this feature (called Google Instant Prediction), so you can't just turn it out like you used to be able to.

I was so sad to see this feature go that I wrote a hack to re-engineer it last night. So far it only works with Google Chrome, but can be adapted to work with all the others:

1. Install Chrome extension [ShortKeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck).
2. Click on the ShortKeys menu and select "Options"
   [image]
3. Click on "Add" and fill in the following fields:

**Keyboard Shortcut:** tab

**Behavior:** Run JavaScript

**Label as:** Result Picker

4. Paste the following JavaScript into the **JavaScript code to run:**

   ```
   document.selectedResultId=0
   function selectResult(newId){
       els = document.querySelectorAll("div.r h3")
       if(newId < 0 || newId >= els.length)
           return  //Could modify for page nav...?
       rp = document.getElementById("result-pointer")
       if(rp != null){
           rp.remove()
       }
       document.selectedResultId=newId
       el = els[newId]
       lnk = el.firstElementChild
       el.innerHTML = "<div id=\"result-pointer\" style=\"position:absolute;left:-15px;\">&gt;</div>" + el.innerHTML
       lnk.focus()
   }
   document.onkeyup=function(event){
       if(event.keyCode==38)
           selectResult(document.selectedResultId-1)
       if(event.keyCode==40)
           selectResult(document.selectedResultId+1)
       if(event.keyCode==13){
         var el = document.querySelectorAll("div.r h3")[document.selectedResultId]
         var lnk = el.parentElement
         var url = lnk.href
         if(event.ctrlKey){
           var win = window.open(url,"_blank")
           win.blur()
           window.open().close()
         }
         else{
           document.location = url
         }
       }
   }
   selectResult(0)
   ```
5. Configure the **Activation Settings**:

**Active while in form fields** (Checked)

**Websites** (Only specific sites)

**URLS (one per line)**: *.google.*

This is what the Options page should look like

[image: ShortKeys Options Page]

6. Click Save and then close your browser.

***Instructions:***

- When you restart you should see a little blue ">" appear by search
  results when you hit tab.
- The up/down arrow keys make it cycle through the results.
- Hitting "Enter" will navigate to the highlighted result.
- Hitting "Ctrl+Enter" to open the result in a new tab.

Happy Searching!

Comment: The Chrome extension is no longer available :( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck

Comment: @user2205916 I hope they bring it back otherwise we'll need to use another extension. Don't forget to follow the question linked at the top; this guy is closed.

Answer (score 19):

As of 2017-07-31, [Google removed this feature entirely from search](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674).

I created the [open source Web Search Navigator extension](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator) to fix this and add extra features (like configurable keyboard shortcuts).

See [installation instructions](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator#installation).

Hope you find it useful, but in any case - feedback is welcome!

Comment: This is brilliant! More people should be aware of it.

Comment: The Chrome-link is 404 now

Comment: @Rheven see updated answer

Comment: It works in 2022.

Comment: Still shines in 2024!

Answer (score 18):

I've created a Chrome extension that will add back the primary keyboard functionality (that I used at least). If the search box isn't focused, pressing any key will automatically focus it. In addition, arrow keys and tab/shift+tab will let you navigate between results. Hopefully this can help us remain productive until Google (hopefully) adds the functionality back.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-result-keyb/iobmefdldoplhmonnnkchglfdeepnfhd?hl=en&gl=US

Here's the code for the extension in case you want to edit it:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var isResultsPage = document.querySelector('html[itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage"]');
  if (!isResultsPage) {
    return;
  }

  var searchbox = document.querySelector('form[role="search"] input[type="text"]:nth-of-type(1)'),
      results = document.querySelectorAll('h3 a'),
      KEY_UP = 38,
      KEY_DOWN = 40,
      KEY_TAB = 9;

  function focusResult(offset) {
    var focused = document.querySelector('h3 a:focus');

    // No result is currently focused. Focus the first one
    if (focused == null) {
      results[0].focus();
    }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var result = results[i];
        if (result === focused) {
          var focusIndex = i + offset;
          if (focusIndex < 0) focusIndex = 0;
          if (focusIndex >= results.length) focusIndex = results.length - 1;
          results[focusIndex].focus();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var isSearchActive = searchbox === document.activeElement,
        keycode = e.keyCode,
        // From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467240/determine-if-javascript-e-keycode-is-a-printable-non-control-character
        isPrintable = (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58)   || // number keys
                      (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91)   || // letter keys
                      (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)  || // numpad keys
                      (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
                      (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223);   // [\]' (in order)

    if ((!isSearchActive && e.keyCode == KEY_DOWN) || (e.keyCode == KEY_TAB && !e.shiftKey)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      focusResult(1); // Focus next
    }
    else if ((!isSearchActive && e.keyCode == KEY_UP) || (e.keyCode == KEY_TAB && e.shiftKey)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      focusResult(-1); // Focus previous
    }
    else if (!isSearchActive && isPrintable) {
      // Otherwise, force caret to end of text and focus the search box
      searchbox.value = searchbox.value + " ";
      searchbox.focus();
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: The author released [the source code of his extension here](https://github.com/jchafik/google-search-shortcuts). It is slightly more advanced than the code snippet above.

Comment: This extension works great, use it almost ever day.

Comment: almost perfect, what I don't like is it indents forward the current highlighted search result

Comment: I realized this can be configured - if you remove the arrow and "add styling" it's 99.9% optimal. Really nice extension!

Comment: heads up, broken right now!

heres an alternative: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-results-sho/dchaandmcifgjemlhiekookpgjmkcelg/related?hl=en&gl=US

Answer (score 5):

For firefox I solve this issue by Google Search Result Keyboard Shortcuts add-on.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-search-result-shortcuts/?src=api

Answer (score 1):

You may try extensions that introduce Vim-like keybindings. With them you'll never need to use your mouse again. For example, [`cVim`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cvim/ihlenndgcmojhcghmfjfneahoeklbjjh?hl=en) is the one that's currently most powerful for Chrome, while `Vimperator` is the one for Firefox.

With such extensions you can access any link on the current page by pressing `f` (by default) followed by a one/two key combination.