# Using the keyboard to open a website in Chrome without tab

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I prefer to use the keyboard instead of the mouse, but I have not yet found a good way to open up Google search results without just pressing tab many times, which takes a long time.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to open the first, second, third, etc. search results in Chrome? If not, would it be possible to program something, maybe with AutoHotkey that could open search results with a hot key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use keyboard to navigate google search results (now that instant search is dead)](https://superuser.com/questions/1234766/how-to-use-keyboard-to-navigate-google-search-results-now-that-instant-search-i)

Answer (score -1):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future 
AutoHotkey releases.

SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
Gui, -Theme +AlwaysOnTop +LastFound +ToolWindow
Gui, Color, 0D0D0D
Gui, Add, Edit, x10 y10 w200 h20 vSM,
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y45 w60 h20 gChrome, Chrome
Gui, Add, Button, x+10 y45 w60 h20 gDuck, Duck
Gui, Add, Button, x+10 y45 w60 h20 gYouTube, YouTube
Gui, Show, xCenter yCenter w220 h100 , SearcMini
Return

Chrome:

    GuiControlGet, SM
    Run, https://www.google.com/search?q=%SM%
    Return

Duck:

    GuiControlGet, SM
    Run, https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%SM%&ia=web=
    Return

YouTube:

    GuiControlGet, SM
    Run, https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%SM%
    Return
    GuiClose:
    ExitApp
    Return
```